# mysql deadlock caused by nested transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

UPDATE: Posted innodb engine status

Can mysql nested transaction cause deadlocks occasionally? Here is the below code

```
//START OVERALL TRANSACTION
$this->db->trans_start();

   //Delete transaction
   $this->db->trans_start();
   $this->db->delete('sales_item_taxes', array('sales_id' => $sale_id)); 

   //END DELETE TRANSACTION
   $this->db->trans_complete();

foreach($this->Item_taxes_finder->get_info($item['item_id']) as $row)
{
    $return = $this->db->insert('sales_items_taxes', array(
        'sale_id'   =>$sale_id,
        'item_id'   =>$item['item_id'],
        'line'      =>$item['line'],
        'name'      =>$row['name'],
        'percent'   =>$row['percent'],
        'cumulative'=>$row['cumulative']
    ));

    if (!$return)
    {
        echo $this->db->_error_number().': '.$this->db->_error_message();
    }
}


$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Occasionally I get the following error:

```
1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

INNODB ENGINE STATUS:

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
| Type   | Name | Status                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| InnoDB |      | 
=====================================
140520 12:00:17 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 15 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 1766819 1_second, 1766816 sleeps, 167043 10_second, 100947 background, 100945 flush
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 1776023
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 236559, signal count 288374
Mutex spin waits 546890, rounds 1796579, OS waits 33216
RW-shared spins 205374, rounds 5519210, OS waits 176937
RW-excl spins 5661, rounds 841678, OS waits 23933
Spin rounds per wait: 3.29 mutex, 26.87 RW-shared, 148.68 RW-excl
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
140520 11:27:44 Transaction:
TRANSACTION 86D125F, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
15 lock struct(s), heap size 3112, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 1910245, OS thread handle 0x7fbf0042e700, query id 56114114 php-pos-web 10.181.16.33 phppoint update
INSERT INTO `phppos_sales_items_taxes` (`sale_id`, `item_id`, `line`, `name`, `percent`, `cumulative`) VALUES (11763, 1115, 3, 'PST', '8.000', '0')
Foreign key constraint fails for table `phppoint_fatpanda`.`phppos_sales_items_taxes`:
,
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_items_taxes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_sales_items` (`sale_id`)
Trying to add in child table, in index `PRIMARY` tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 8 fields;
 0: len 4; hex 80002df3; asc   - ;;
 1: len 4; hex 8000045b; asc    [;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
 3: len 3; hex 505354; asc PST;;
 4: len 8; hex 8000000000080000; asc         ;;
 5: len 6; hex 0000086d125f; asc    m _;;
 6: len 7; hex 00000000000000; asc        ;;
 7: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;

But in parent table `phppoint_fatpanda`.`phppos_sales_items`, in index `PRIMARY`,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 11; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80002df1; asc   - ;;
 1: len 4; hex 8000049a; asc     ;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 3: len 6; hex 0000086cfd29; asc    l );;
 4: len 7; hex f400000216012c; asc       ,;;
 5: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 6: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 7: len 11; hex 8000000000010000000000; asc            ;;
 8: len 11; hex 8000000000100000000000; asc            ;;
 9: len 11; hex 80000000002d0000000000; asc      -     ;;
 10: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;

------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
140520 11:27:44
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 86D11A3, ACTIVE 2 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 9, locked 9
LOCK WAIT 364 lock struct(s), heap size 47544, 80177 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1910243, OS thread handle 0x7fbeb2090700, query id 56113840 10.181.26.42 phppoint Copying to tmp table
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE phppos_sales_items_temp
        (SELECT phppos_sales.deleted as deleted,phppos_sales.deleted_by as deleted_by, sale_time, date(sale_time) as sale_date, phppos_sales_items.sale_id, comment,payment_type, customer_id, employee_id, 
        phppos_items.item_id, NULL as item_kit_id, supplier_id, quantity_purchased, item_cost_price, item_unit_price, category, 
        discount_percent, (item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100) as subtotal,
        phppos_sales_items.line as line, serialnumber, phppos_sales_items.description as description,
        (item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)+(item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative != 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END)/100) 
        +(((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quanti
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 454941 page no 114 n bits 408 index `location_id` of table `phppoint_fatpanda`.`phppos_sales` trx id 86D11A3 lock mode S waiting
Record lock, heap no 335 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80002df3; asc   - ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 86D125D, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
23 lock struct(s), heap size 3112, 12 row lock(s), undo log entries 10
MySQL thread id 1910245, OS thread handle 0x7fbf0042e700, query id 56114091 php-pos-web 10.181.16.33 phppoint update
INSERT INTO `phppos_sales_items_taxes` (`sale_id`, `item_id`, `line`, `name`, `percent`, `cumulative`) VALUES (11763, 1178, 2, 'GST', '5.000', '0')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 454941 page no 114 n bits 408 index `location_id` of table `phppoint_fatpanda`.`phppos_sales` trx id 86D125D lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 335 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80002df3; asc   - ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 454945 page no 386 n bits 288 index `PRIMARY` of table `phppoint_fatpanda`.`phppos_sales_items_taxes` trx id 86D125D lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 86E47F7
Purge done for trx's n:o < 86E45C0 undo n:o < 0
History list length 1418
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 86E47F6, not started
MySQL thread id 1913171, OS thread handle 0x7fbeb2090700, query id 56205829 10.181.26.42 phppoint
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 1913095, OS thread handle 0x7fbf005b4700, query id 56205830 localhost root
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
3599456 OS file reads, 9300371 OS file writes, 3988632 OS fsyncs
0.27 reads/s, 16384 avg bytes/read, 13.07 writes/s, 7.27 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 84, seg size 86, 55915 merges
merged operations:
 insert 68506, delete mark 4761, delete 38
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 2212699, node heap has 751 buffer(s)
5050.86 hash searches/s, 624.09 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 184365806376
Log flushed up to   184365806376
Last checkpoint at  184365791715
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
2149282 log i/o's done, 3.47 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 1098907648; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 62951505
Buffer pool size   65536
Free buffers       1
Database pages     64784
Old database pages 23894
Modified db pages  88
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 4073451, not young 0
0.07 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 3592230, created 1542046, written 6130789
0.27 reads/s, 18.00 creates/s, 6.40 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 64784, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[382]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 15866, id 140457065543424, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 77431960, updated 1673031, deleted 160450, read 4825684197
1103.93 inserts/s, 2.53 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 7772.15 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
 |
+--------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: there are no nested transactions in this code. you start a trans, you do a delete, you finish the trans, then you start doing some inserts. Unless that "get_info()" function does some DB operations itself, there's no way this code could produce a deadlock.

Comment: get_info does perform a database operation. Also; I have posted INNODB ENGINE STATUS

Comment: so, yeah. there you go. you're doing inserts/selects on the same table, creating temp tables using selects, etc... depending on the order of your operations, you can definitely create deadlocks.

Comment: The temporary table query should be easily be done by the time the sale is submitted. How long does a temporary table hold a lock?

Comment: If the temporary table query on a different connection could that cause a lock? If I don't use transactions would this fix the problem?

Comment: definitely. locks are a "global" thing. wouldn't be much point if user A locks a record, but user B can still go rummage around in there. transactions keep YOUR code sequences separate, locks keep OTHER people from messaging around in your sandbox

Comment: If I remove the transaction would this fix the deadlock? I only really have the transaction for safety, but don't really need it if I have deadlock issues.

Comment: can't answer that. no idea if your delete query is a SINGLE delete query (which'd be an atomic operation anyways), or a series of deletes (which you'd probably done in a transaction).

Comment: There are multiple deletes from multiple tables. Each delete is on operation

Answer (score 0):

you can use batch_insert() in codeigniter

```
//START OVERALL TRANSACTION
$this->db->trans_start();

   //Delete transaction
   $this->db->trans_start();
   $this->db->delete('sales_item_taxes', array('sales_id' => $sale_id)); 

$data = array();

foreach($this->Item_taxes_finder->get_info($item['item_id']) as $row)
{

    $data[] = array(
        'sale_id'   =>$sale_id,
        'item_id'   =>$item['item_id'],
        'line'      =>$item['line'],
        'name'      =>$row['name'],
        'percent'   =>$row['percent'],
        'cumulative'=>$row['cumulative']
    );

}

$this->db->insert_batch('sales_items_taxes', $data); 

$this->db->trans_complete();

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

Comment: I understand I could use this; but is the reason why it is failing using the current way? (It only fails occasionally).

Comment: may be, you have closed the transaction before the insert operations and next time you did not open the transaction again but you are closing the transaction at end